# Funds still showing in old Armory wallet/address after being sent+confirmed to new Electrum one?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, electrum, armory

I'm having a bit of an issue that I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will be able to clarify.   I've had an old wallet using the full node client "Armory" for a few years, with 0.2 BTC within that I'd like to send to my new Electrum wallet.

After trying to send without a fee a few times and having it rejected by the network  (Armory has a pop-up window with a link to the transaction, saying something like "if it doesn't show up on this blockchain.info transaction link in a minute, nobody picked it up so try again and this time send a fee"), I decided to have it send with a fee of 0.0001 BTC.  Armory still told me that by its calculation this wasn't enough (it suggested something like .00015555 or different amounts close to that range), but this time once I waited a moment I saw the transaction post to the blockchain.info link!    My Electrum wallet also registered the arrival of the 0.1999 BTC and started to add confirmations - as of this writing it has 68 confirmations  and the new Electrum wallet  shows that amount as a balance.   On the surface all would be well except...

My Armory wallet doesn't seem to show the money has left the wallet, still suggesting a spendable balance of 0.2 BTC!  It doesn't show in the transaction log either.  I figured this may be because it just hasn't "seen" the block as of yet, so I decided to  restart Armory even though it was currently connected to the network.  Having restarted and waited for it to go through its whole process, it still doesn't seem to notice the money is gone. I thought that Armory, because it is a full node client (and takes all that huge HDD space) would "have" to know that it happened.   The pop-up I got when I sent the funds telling me to wait and see on Blockchain if the transaction was accepted or not mentioned that Armory would "learn" about it from the network if it was..so I'm surprised it hasn't thus far.

The most likely issue I can think of is that Armory hasn't caught up yet.  According to Armory, it is "Connected" and received its last block 1.5 hours ago and has 348324 blocks currently.  However, I noticed that according to blockchain.info linked from my Electrum wallet's transaction, it takes place on block 393144 (the transaction was made probably close to 15+ hours ago) so assuming blocks are added sequentially, it would seem Armory doesn't see it yet, right?  Why would this be? After all the time it takes for Armory to connect to the network, catch up, deal with its data bases etc.. I would expect it to be up to date, not approximately 5000 blocks behind if Armory shows it is "connected"?

Is it likely the hypothesis that the transaction just hasn't been understood yet by Armory is accurate?  If so, why it so far from current?   Any other ideas  or possible issues?  Thansks

Answer (score 1):

It's not Armory that hasn't caught up, but your bitcoind that hasn't caught up. Armory works on top of bitcoind and gets all the block information from the local bitcoind node. It looks like the bitcoind node has about 50,000 blocks to catch up before Armory will notice that the bitcoin is gone. Just let bitcoind catch up (how long will depend on your network bandwidth and your computer's RAM/CPU) and you'll see it once the blocks catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to reinstall the Armory 0.96 and this time I notice using the "Resource Monitor" that bitcoind, ArmoryDB and ArmoryQt were working well.
Try Resource Monitor in your computer to verify if bitcoind is working.
Good luck